# @Input property is undefined in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular12

The problem is simple to understand and tricky to find the solution. I've 2 components as below:

1. CustomerComponent (Parent)
2. InvoiceComponent (Child)

Now, I'm passing customer details as `<admin-invoice-form [customer]="customer"></admin-invoice-form>`  from parent component to child component. But, when I see the input property of the child component in the constructor( ) and ngOnInit( ), the result is `undefined`.

**Look at the code below to understand this better,**

**1. admin.customer.components.ts** file

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from 'src/app/model/customer';
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/services/customer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-customers',
  templateUrl: './admin-customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-customers.component.css']
})
export class AdminCustomersComponent {
  customerArray: Customer[] = [];
  customer: Customer;

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {
    this.customerService.getAll()
       .subscribe((customer: Customer[]) => {
           this.customerArray = customer;
      });
  }

  setCustomer(customer: Customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
  }
}
```

**2. admin-customers.component.html** file

```html
<div class="container">
     <table class="table table-striped table-hover border" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
                <th class="text-center">Mobile No</th>
                <th class="text-center">City</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
             <tr *ngFor="let customer of customerArray">
                    <td class="text-center">{{ customer.firstName}} </td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ customer.lastName }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ customer.mobileNo }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ customer.city }}</td>
                   
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="setCustomer(customer)" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#custInvoiceModal">
                            Generate Invoice
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>          
        </tbody>
    </table>
    

    <!-- Invoice Modal: Starts -->
    <div id="printThis"> 
        <div class="modal fade" id="custInvoiceModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="custInvoiceLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <!-- Child Component: Starts -->
            <admin-invoice-form [customer]="customer"></admin-invoice-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**3. admin-invoice-form.component.ts** file

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from 'src/app/model/customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-invoice-form',
  templateUrl: './admin-invoice-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-invoice-form.component.css']
})
export class AdminInvoiceFormComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
  @Input('customer') customer: Customer; // this will be provided from it's consumer i.e. admin-customers.component.html
  
  
  constructor() { 
    console.log('inside constructor()');
    console.log(this.customer); // Output: undefined
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('inside ngOnInit()');
    console.log(this.customer); // Output: undefined   
  }
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes['customer']){
      console.log('inside ngOnChanges()');
      console.log(this.customer); // Output: undefined
    }
      
  }
  
}
```

**This is how I'm getting an error after adding `*ngIf="customer"` on the child component.**

[image: child-component-error]

Answer (score 1):

The below solution has solved my problem,

**1. Instantiating customer to empty object inside the parent class before calling `setCustomer(customer)` method.**

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from 'src/app/model/customer';
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/services/customer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-customers',
  templateUrl: './admin-customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-customers.component.css']
})
export class AdminCustomersComponent {
  customerArray: Customer[] = [];
  customer: Customer = new Customer(); // instantiate to empty object initially

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {
    this.customerService.getAll()
       .subscribe((customer: Customer[]) => {
           this.customerArray = customer;
      });
  }

  setCustomer(customer: Customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
  }
}
```

**2. Create ngOnChange() method and do the rest of the stuff with updated `@Input('customer') customer;`**

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from 'src/app/model/customer';
import { Invoice } from 'src/app/model/invoice';
import { Item } from 'src/app/model/item';

@Component({
  selector: 'admin-invoice-form',
  templateUrl: './admin-invoice-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-invoice-form.component.css']
})
export class AdminInvoiceFormComponent implements OnChanges{
  @Input('customer') customer: Customer; // this will be provided from it's conumer i.e. admin-customers.component.html
  invoice: Invoice; // for invoice details
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes['customer']){
      this.invoice = new Invoice(this.customer);
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: This helped me thanks. You can mark it as the answer so it can help other people to see the problem was solved :)

Comment: @Sarah, thanks for the compliments. However, it's already marked as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see where do you call `setCustomer()` ??

but anyway i think you can solve your problem like this:
`<admin-invoice-form *ngIf="customer" [customer]="customer"></admin-invoice-form>`

so the component will be created only when customer is not null or undefined

Comment: `setCustomer( )` is called on click of Generate Invoice Button in html table body. Anyway, I've tried the same solution suggested by you but I'm getting other error i.e. my bootstrap model is not rendering on click of Generate Invoice button because using `*ngIf="customer"` it's not finding the customer initially and so the component is not getting created.

Comment: Do I need to instantiate the customer initially like **`customer: Customer = new Customer( );`** to avoid this issue?

Comment: this is strange, what error do you exactly get?
Anyway an alternative solution would be to use getter/setter in  AdminInvoiceFormComponent:
```typescript
  private _customer:Customer;
  @Input() set customer(customer: Customer) {
    this._customer = customer;
    // do your stuff here
  }
  get _customer():Customer {
    return this._customer;
  }
```

Comment: If I instantiate the customer in the parent component like **`customer: Customer = new Customer( );`** then the problem is solved and I don't even need to write **`ngIf="customer"`** condition because for the first time it will find the empty customer. And, in our child component, I instantiate the invoice class inside **`ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)`**  method. **Look at the solution code below. If you see any improvement and need of refactoring then kindly let me know.**

Comment: **See the error in image above.** Also, note that the child component is not rendered because it is not created. Everytime, when we click on Generate Invoice, it calls the child component but the child component has `*ngIf` condition so initially it is not finding the customer and so it is not creating the bootstrap modal and not rendering it.

Comment: ahh i get it why you get an error...
your solution looks fine, but maybe the solution with `@Input() set customer(customer: Customer) { ...`would be a bit more performant

Comment: Thanks, Zerotwelve for your feedback. **Yes, we can change it to a setter method** that's not a big deal I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the detection strategy to onpush in your child

```
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-invoice-form',
  templateUrl: './admin-invoice-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-invoice-form.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Comment: **How does this help? Could you kindly elaborate on `changeDetectionStrategy` to understand it better?**

Comment: Benefits of onPush Change Detection
No Unnecessary Dirty Check in the Child Components
Faster Component Re-rendering

Comment: But what I read about change Detection seems scary to me. Read this post  https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/ 
It talks about mutating the object directly creates the problems using OnPush.

Comment: You can check this link: https://www.webagesolutions.com/blog/advanced-components-concepts-in-angular